# How can I use scrollview with relative layout

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Continue" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="22dp"></Button>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dealerText"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="@string/dealerNoString" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_below="@+id/dealerText" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/DealerString" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dealerText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/dealerText" android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="33dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1" android:layout_marginTop="28dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"></EditText>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I used relative layout,But I have many EditTexts so ,how can I use scroll view with relative layout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Continue" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="22dp"></Button>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dealerText"></EditText>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="@string/dealerNoString" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_below="@+id/dealerText" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/DealerString" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dealerText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/dealerText" android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"></EditText>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="33dp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1" android:layout_marginTop="28dp"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"></EditText>
     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Wrapping it around!

Comment: And remember that a ScrollView can always have only 1 child at a time

Comment: it's true! that's why we need a layout to wrap around child views

Answer (score 0):

Place the RelativeLayout inside of the ScrollView since it can only take one view. And then place the EditText's inside of the RelativeLayout. If this is what you mean.