# Scrollview doesn't scroll in relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        layout="@layout/header"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/insurance"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Insurance Co." />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/insuranceBranch"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Insurance Co.Branch" >
                </EditText>

                <Spinner 
                    android:id="@+id/insuranceProduct"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>            

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/policyNumber"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Policy Number" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/idv"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="IDV/SI" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/registrationNumber"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Registration Number" >
                </EditText>            

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/makeAndModel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Make and Model" >
                </EditText>            

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/manufacturingYear"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Manufacturing Year" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/insuranceRemark"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Insurance Remark" >
                </EditText>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Add"/>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Cancel"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You probably should put first ScrollView and then Relative Layout inside. See this answers:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714442/how-can-i-use-scrollview-with-relative-layout and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657687/relativelayout-scrollview

Comment: You should fix the ScrollView Height. Dont use wrap content

Answer (score 0):

Try putting match_parent for layout_height for ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/insurance"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Insurance Co." />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/insuranceBranch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Insurance Co.Branch" >
            </EditText>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/insuranceProduct"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/policyNumber"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Policy Number" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/idv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="IDV/SI" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registrationNumber"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Registration Number" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/makeAndModel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Make and Model" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/manufacturingYear"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Manufacturing Year" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/insuranceRemark"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Insurance Remark" >
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your layout will scroll now just added 
  android:layout_above="@+id/addcancel_layout"
one of your scrollview element is hiding on back of linearlayout

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/header" 
    layout="@layout/header"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" >
    <ScrollView
  android:layout_above="@+id/addcancel_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/insurance"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Insurance Co." />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/insuranceBranch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Insurance Co.Branch" >
            </EditText>

            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/insuranceProduct"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>            

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/policyNumber"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Policy Number" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/idv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="IDV/SI" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registrationNumber"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Registration Number" >
            </EditText>            

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/makeAndModel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Make and Model" >
            </EditText>            

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/manufacturingYear"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Manufacturing Year" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/insuranceRemark"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Insurance Remark" >
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/addcancel_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Cancel"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```